# jOOQ code generator

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I used a jOOQ program code to generate a database but now I have some problems. In the database, I have table A and B. The first time all had generated pojo, dao, interface and so on. After some development over a period of time, I found that the table A needs to add some fields or modify some fields, so I'd have to code again and then jOOQ code generator will overwrite the existing code, which makes me very sad. When I use "exclude A" With the exclusion of A table, it was found that only the data of Table A was generated and Table B would be deleted. I do not know how to deal with this problem. My code generator is as follows:

```
public class JooqCodegen {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                    .withDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microedudb")
                    .withUser("root")
                    .withPassword("root")
                )
                .withGenerator(
                        new Generator()
                        .withName("org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator")
                        .withGenerate(new Generate()
                            .withPojos(true)
                            .withImmutablePojos(true)
                            .withInterfaces(true)
                            .withDaos(true)
                            .withSpringAnnotations(true)
                            .withJavaTimeTypes(true)
                        )
                        .withDatabase(new Database()
                                .withName("org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                                //.withIncludes(".*")
                                .withExcludes("A")
                                .withDateAsTimestamp(true)
                                .withInputSchema("microedudb")
                        )
                        .withTarget(new Target()
                                .withPackageName("com.chunfytseng.microedu.jooq")
                                .withDirectory("src/main/java")
                        )
                        );
            GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jOOQ code generator always produces a snapshot of your database schema at the time the code is being generated. This meanst that any table that is not generated (e.g. because of the `<exclude/>` configuration) is deleted from the generation output. That's important because you could've dropped the table too, which would have the same effect.

> so I'd have to code again and then jOOQ code generator will overwrite the existing code

You should never manually modify generated code. Instead, every time you add / remove a column in the database, you should regenerate your entire schema.